# Why my button isnt in the same row as the form and the string?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I cant find the way to put the button on the same line as the form and text in responsive desing for mobile.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 nopadding">
                <div class="row col-xs-8 col-md-8 pts-vcenter">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                        <span class="bold">{l s='Voucher' mod='onepagecheckoutps'}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-7 col-md-7 nopadding-xs">
                        <input type="text" class="discount_name form-control" id="discount_name" name="discount_name" value="{if isset($discount_name) && $discount_name}{$discount_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{/if}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <span type="button" id="submitAddDiscount" name="submitAddDiscount" class="btn btn-default btn-small">
                        {l s='Add' mod='onepagecheckoutps'}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I´ve tried to put them all together in the 3rd div as I thought vcenter can solve my problem, but nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `col-xs-12` like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <span type="button" id="submitAddDiscount" name="submitAddDiscount" class="btn btn-default btn-small">
  {l s='Add' mod='onepagecheckoutps'}
  </span>
</div>
```

And don't forget to use the row class :)